# How to detect the width of the textItem and position the another item to the right

Tags: qt, qml, qtextedit

I have a QML TextItem where text is been set dynamically.width i cant determine as the text can have any number of characters. 
and i need to place another text item next to it .
so how to anchor to the right of the text item when we cant determine the width of the text as the text can grow any time. Wrap or Elide is not allowed

Ex:

```
Text
    {
        id: distance
        width: //dont know what to provide

        font.bold: true

        verticalAlignment:Text.AlignBottom
        horizontalAlignment:Text.AlignLeft
        maximumLineCount: 1

        onTextChanged:
        {
            console.log("$$$$$___Text is been changed:" + txt_distance.paintedWidth +" "+ paintedHeight)

        }

        anchors
        {
            bottom: parent.bottom
            bottomMargin: 2
            left: parent.left
            leftMargin: 20
            right: //Dont know what to give

        }
```

and the neighbour item

```
Text
    {
        id: address

        font.bold: true

        verticalAlignment:Text.AlignBottom
        horizontalAlignment:Text.AlignLeft
        maximumLineCount: 1

        anchors
        {
            bottom: parent.bottom
            bottomMargin: 2
            left: distance.right <-- Please help 
            right: parent.right
            rightMargin: 20
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to explicitly set the `width` as it will be set to the `paintedWidth`.

Your example could be simplified like this:

```
Text {
    id: distance
    text: "Hello"
}

Text {
    text: "Wagmare"
    anchors.left: distance.right
}
```

An even better solution would be to use a `Row`:

```
Row {
    Text {
        text: "Hello"
    }

    Text {
        text: "Wagmare"
    }
}
```

See [Use Case - Displaying Text In QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-usecase-text.html)

> If the width or height is not explicitly set, reading these properties
>   will return the parameters of the bounding rect of the text (if you
>   have explicitly set width or height, you can still use paintedWidth
>   and paintedHeight).

Comment: Thanks augre . What if the text is been set at runtime ? . Like in .cpp after receving data i will update the text property. will it work ?

Comment: Yes if you don't manually set the width it will still be bound to the paintedWidth if the text changes. You can try it with a timer : `Timer {
        id: timer
        onTriggered: distance.text = "Hi"
    }
    Component.onCompleted: timer.start()`